# using a function in where clause for SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, function

I'm trying to use a function in the where clause to get the previous business date in order to calculate the delta of a column in the table

I'm using the following query which isn't working:

```
select db1.x, db2.date, db1.date, db1.y as ValNow, db2.y as ValPrevious 
from db db1, db db2 
where db1.x = 275305 
  and db1.x = db2.x 
  and (dbo.getLastBusinessDate(db1.date) = db2.date) 
order by db1.date
```

I need to use the function because it will include special dates where there are no values

EDIT:

Sorry for the vague message the error that I'm getting is

Msg 557, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

I just want to display the values side by side right now to confirm that the sql statement is working correctly, I planned to use the following statement to calculate delta

```
select db1.date, db1.x, (db1.y - db2.y)  as delta , DAY(db1.date), DAY(db2.date)
from 
    db db1
    inner JOIN db db2 on db1.x = db2.x and dbo.getLastBusinessDate(db1.date) = db2.date
order by date desc
```

Comment: You should only tag one rdbms.(sql server, mysql)

Comment: Also, not working is very vague.  You should explain what the problem is and include the error message in the question.

Comment: A UDF needs a schema qualifier in T-SQL (`dbo.getLastBusinessDate()`)

Comment: @AlexK.: Schema qualifier is not required for MySQL - OP needs to clarify which rdbms.

Comment: I removed all of the schemas because they contained sensitive names.

Answer (score 0):

First you use `LEFT JOIN` because first date doesnt have "previous date". You may want handle that null.

Then in the join you use doble condition, first `db1.x = db2.x` and `db1.date > db2.date` to make sure you match an early date.

In the `where` you have to make sure you select the exact previous date.

This should work in both MySql or SqlServer, but in sql server you can use window function for a better result.

```
SELECT 
   db1.x, 
   db2.date, 
   db1.date, 
   db1.y as ValNow, 
   db2.y as ValPrevious 
FROM  
     db db1 
LEFT JOIN db db2 
   ON  db1.x = db2.x
  AND  db1.date > db2.date
WHERE db1.x = 275305 
 AND not exist (SELECT db3.date
                FROM db db3
                WHERE db3.date > db2.date 
                 AND  db3.date < db1.date)                 
ORDER BY db1.date
```